# Points on highest record in Mysql

Tags: mysql

My table

```
+------+-------+--------+
| NAME | MARKS | POINTS |
+------+-------+--------+
| S1   |    53 | (null) |
| S2   |    55 | (null) |
| S3   |    56 | (null) |
| S4   |    55 | (null) |
| S5   |    52 | (null) |
| S6   |    51 | (null) |
| S7   |    53 | (null) |
+------+-------+--------+
```

Refer : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5d046/1

I would like to add 3,2,1 points to the highest Marks. Here S3 goes to 3 points, S2,S4 goes to 2 points and S1,S7 goes to 1 points.

Final outputs looks,

```
+------+-------+--------+
| NAME | MARKS | POINTS |
+------+-------+--------+
| S1   |    53 |   1    |
| S2   |    55 |   2    |
| S3   |    56 |   3    |
| S4   |    55 |   2    |
| S5   |    52 |   0    |
| S6   |    51 |   0    |
| S7   |    53 |   1    |
+------+-------+--------+
```

Plz help

Comment: +1 for including the SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it via variables (see samples in other answers), or via `case`:

```
select 
  myTable.*,
  case
    when max1.marks is not null then 3
    when max2.marks is not null then 2
    when max3.marks is not null then 1
    else 0
  end as score
from
  myTable
  LEFT JOIN
  (select marks from myTable order by marks desc limit 1) AS max1
  ON myTable.marks=max1.marks
  LEFT JOIN
  (select marks from myTable order by marks desc limit 2,1) AS max2
  ON myTable.marks=max2.marks
  LEFT JOIN
  (select marks from myTable order by marks desc limit 3,1) AS max3
  ON myTable.marks=max3.marks;
```

the demo can be found [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5d046/73).

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion is that you first calculate the ranking of each mark, and then use that in a case statement in an update.

The following query shows one way to calculate the ranking:

```
select t.*,
       @rn := if(@marks = marks, @rn, @rn + 1) as ranking,
       @marks := marks
from myTable t cross join
     (select @rn := 0, @marks := -1) const
order by t.marks desc;
```

(As a note:  I am a bit uncomfortable with this method, because MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of the two expressions with constants.  If `@marks` were set before `@rn`, then it wouldn't work.  In practice, that does not seem to happen.  And, this is more efficient that the equivalent with a correlated subquery.)

You can then put this into an `update` using `join`:

```
update myTable join
       (select t.*,
               @rn := if(@marks = marks, @rn, @rn + 1) as ranking,
               @marks := marks
        from myTable t cross join
             (select @rn := 0, @marks := -1) const
        order by t.marks desc
       ) mr
       on myTable.Name = mr.Name
    set myTable.Points := (case when mr.ranking = 1 then 3
                                when mr.ranking = 2 then 2
                                when mr.ranking = 3 then 1
                                else 0
                           end);
```

This has been tested on your SQL Fiddle.

Comment: +1 as I just saw he wants to reward all of them with points and not only my plumb ( deleted ) ORDER BY MARKS LIMIT 3 solution

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE myTable t1
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT @row:=@row-1 AS RowPoints, Marks
FROM (
  SELECT Marks
  FROM myTable
  GROUP BY Marks
  ORDER BY Marks DESC
  LIMIT 3
) AS TopMarks
INNER JOIN (SELECT @row:=4) AS RowInit
) AS AddPoints ON t1.Marks = AddPoints.Marks
SET Points = COALESCE(Points, 0) + AddPoints.RowPoints;
```

This should work just fine. You should and and index on the Marks column.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this:

```
SELECT t.Name Name, t.Marks Marks,

 (CASE WHEN Marks = (Select max(marks) from mytable) THEN 3 ELSE 0 END+

CASE WHEN Marks = (Select min(marks) from (Select distinct marks 
    from mytable order by marks desc limit 2) a) THEN 2 ELSE 0 END+

CASE WHEN Marks = (Select min(marks) from (Select distinct marks 
    from mytable order by marks desc limit 3) b) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

AS `Points`
FROM mytable t;
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5d046/98/0)**

Comment: Great. Very simple query, easy to follow.